# NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager & Jetty

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I am trying to use the [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://iain.cx/src/nssm/) to run Jetty that is included with Solr as a Windows Service. Everything works fine by placing Java.exe in my C:\solr folder and setting up NSSM by pointing to this Java.exe along with the following parameters `-Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr -jar start.jar`

You can also run `C:\solr\java.exe -Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr -jar C:/solr/start.jar` from the command line without installing the service as a test which works fine.

If I leave Java.exe in the System32 folder though, things will not work and I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.

I can of course run `C:\solr\java -Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr -jar C:/solr/start.jar` as well since Java is in my PATH.

If seems like I need an additional classpath option or something but I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the following in the arguments for NSSM: `-Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr/ -Djetty.home=C:/solr/ -Djetty.logs=C:/solr/logs/ -cp C:/solr/lib/*.jar;C:/solr/start.jar -jar C:/solr/start.jar`